# CUDA: Ошибка при компиляции программы

Tags: c, cuda, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу помочь. Компиляция программы не проходит из-за ошибок типа "identifier is undefined in device code".  Пояснение по программе: есть реализация AES от Брайена Гладмана (Brian Gladman, Worcester, UK), которую я хочу использовать в своей cuda-программе.  Ошибка, мешающая компиляции, возникает при использовании макроса в коде Брайена. Например, в строчке:

```
ke8(cx->ks, 0); ke8(cx->ks, 1);
```

ke8 - это макрос, его код:

```
#define ke8(k,i) \
{ kef8(k,i); \
    k[8*(i)+12] = ss[4] ^= ls_box(ss[3],0); \
    k[8*(i)+13] = ss[5] ^= ss[4]; \
    k[8*(i)+14] = ss[6] ^= ss[5]; \
    k[8*(i)+15] = ss[7] ^= ss[6]; \
}
```

Насколько я понял, такая ошибка связана с макросами, и во время компиляции он не определяется cuda-устройством. Хотя, буквально 2-мя строчками выше "ke8(cx->ks, i);" работает без нареканий, а ведь там тоже работает тот же самый макрос. Гугль-поиск решения этой проблемы не дал.

Из-за чего может возникать ошибка "identifier is undefined in device code", и как её решить?

Comment: На основании приведенных данных ничего сказать нельзя. Что такое ls_box, kef8?

Comment: Весь код своей программы опубликовать здесь невозможно из-за его объёма.Код Брайена, в котором при компиляции появилась описанная выше ошибка, можно скачать тут: gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/AES/aes-src-12-09-11.zip
В архиве откройте aeskey.c а там найдите функцию AES_RETURN aes_encrypt_key256()
Оригинальный код Брайена рабочий, мои переделки под CUDA минимальны.
kef8 - это другой макрос, в том же коде. ls_box - макрос из aesopt.c
Давайте всё-таки разберёмся, из-за чего может возникать ошибка "identifier is undefined in device code", и как её решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка

> `identifier is undefined in device code`

возникает в том случае, если идентификатор не определен. Поскольку, глядя на макрос, трудно сказать, во что он раскрывается, рекомендуется посмотреть на файл, полученный из исходника препроцессором. Для этого в C/C++/Preprocessor, выставить Generate Preprocessed File в YES. После компиляции посмотреть на код, оставшийся от макроса, и обратить внимание на те переменные, которые трактуются как необъявленные. Если их реально нет, значит, что-то не подключено (библиотека или заголовок).

Comment: Благодарю, сделаю как Вы сказали.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить директиву препроцессора *GPU*, в противном случае фиксированные поисковые таблици не определены в памяти устройства, а в памяти хоста и CUDA не может их найти.